# Запрос GET Ajax и русский текст

Tags: кодировка, php

На стороне сервера получаю $_GET в такой кодировке: Ð¼Ð¾Ð
Везде стоит UTF-8(на клиенте и на сервере)
Как можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

точно везде? утф8 должна быть в:

- php файле
- htaccess
- на всякий случай в теге meta charset
- и в настройках браузера

Comment: Da, vezde, v etom i problema

Comment: Esli v php otdaet kak echo json_encode(); die(); kak propisati kodirovku?

Comment: а в базе ?

Comment: база не имеет отношения. в самом Get крокодил..в базе Utf-8 general_ci

Comment: так вам данные  в таком виде приходят ? заголовки смотрите в devtools

Answer (score 1):

Если бы у вас было UTF8 везде, то подобных проблем бы не было. 
Проверьте кодировку самих файлов, она должна быть UTF8.
База тоже может является причиной, допустим кодировка там установлена Utf-8 general_ci, но данные занесены в иной кодировке.

Comment: Подставил запрос напрямую в phpmyadmin, выдает все правильно:

SELECT * 
FROM  `country` 
WHERE CountryName LIKE  'О%'
LIMIT 0 , 30

В браузере стоит кодировка utf-8, в htaccess тоже. В настройках апача UTF-8. файлы проверим - были в кодировке UTF-8 без Bom.
Таблицы в базе в utf-8_general_ci

Comment: Я ведь ясно объяснил - что сам GET корявый приходит

Comment: echo mb_detect_encoding($query, 'UTF-8');  выдает utf-8

Comment: Nikto ne znaet, vidimo

Comment: попробуй перед запросом в phpmyadmin сделать SET NAMES UTF8;